# JSON pass null value to MVC 4 controller in IE9

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

I got some problem while posting JSON data into MVC 4 controller.
Below method is working fine in Firefox but unfortunately failed in IE 9

The JavaScript :

```
var newCustomer = {
    CustName: $("#CustName").val(),
    CustLocalName: $("#CustLocalName").val(),
    CustNumber: $("#CustNumber").val(),
    CountryID: $("#SelectCountry").val(),
    City: $("#City").val()
};

$.ajax({
     url: '@Url.Content("~/CustomerHeader/CreateCustomerHeader")',
     cache: false,
     type: "POST",
     dataType: "json",
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',                     
     data: JSON.stringify(newCustomer),
     success: function (mydata) {
         $("#message").html("Success");
     },
     error: function () {
         $("#message").html("Save failed");
     }
});
```

and this is my controller :

```
public JsonResult CreateCustomerHeader(CustomerHeader record)
{
    try
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)    
        {
            return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = "Form is not valid! Please correct   it and try again." });
        }

        RepositoryHeader.Update(record);

        return Json(new { Result = "OK", Record = record});
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
    }
}
```

the "data" variable as in `public JsonResult CreateCustomerHeader(CustomerHeader **data**)` is getting NULL but while using FireFox it holds the correct value.

UPDATE : New method trying using $.post

```
function CreateNewCustomer(newCustomer) {
    $.post("/CustomerHeader/CreateCustomerHeader",
      newCustomer,
      function (response, status, jqxhr) {
          console.log(response.toString())
      });
}
```

Comment: Might what to give Glimpse (http://getglimpse.com/) a try; it'll help you figure out if the data is being sent but not bound properly.

Comment: done installing and the "CreateCustomerHeader" inspected.it shows clearly the value is there in Model Binding if I am using Firefox but in IE, the value is not there. Even though the "newCustomer" variable containing values

Comment: Good; that directly eliminates one of the more common problems. So, you probably should open IE's developer tools (F12) and open the Console tab, then add a `console.log(JSON.stringify(newCustomer))` somewhere before the ajax call. You might also want to use a `try{ .. }catch(error){ ... }` and `console.log()` the error (if there is one).

Comment: console command added into script and the output is  LOG: {"CustName":"CustomerX","CustLocalName":"","CustNumber":"","CountryID":"4","City":"CustomerC"}. Somehow the try didnot catch any error which I believe it is none. The value is there, so I just don;t get it why IE cannot get it :-(

Comment: Hmm. The only other odd thing I see is this: `@Url.Content("~/CustomerHeader/CreateCustomerHeader")`; if this is supposed to map to an action, you should be using `@Url.Action("CreateCustomerHeader", "CustomerHeader")`. I doubt that is the issue, though.

Comment: try it and still no luck.actually the original method is communicated successfully with controller, only the parameter not being passed using IE9.while using @Url.Action("CreateCustomerHeader", "CustomerHeader") not trigger the controller at all.

Comment: If it's not a hard requirement to post JSON data, I could add an answer showing how to simplify what you're doing, using `jQuery.post()`. Otherwise, not sure what the problem is without seeing more of the project.

Comment: kindly gimme one example :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all I would like to apologize @Tieson.T for not providing details on JavaScript section of the view. The problem is actually caused by $('#addCustomerHeaderModal').modal('hide') that occurred just after ajax call.

The full script :

```
try{ ..

    var newCustomer =
                {
                    CustName: $("#CustName").val(),
                    CustLocalName: $("#CustLocalName").val(),
                    CustNumber: $("#CustNumber").val(),
                    CountryID: $("#SelectCountry").val(),
                    City: $("#City").val()
                };


             $.ajax({                 
                 url: '/CustomerHeader/CreateCustomerHeader',
                 cache: false,
                 type: "POST",
                 dataType: "json",
                 data: JSON.stringify(newCustomer),
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                 

                 success: function (mydata) {
                     $("#message").html("Success");
                 },
                 error: function () {
                     $("#message").html("Save failed");
                 }
             });

             }

             catch(Error) {
                 console.log(Error.toString());
             }

             //$('#addCustomerHeaderModal').modal('hide')//THIS is the part that causing controller cannot retrieve the data but happened only with IE!
```

I have commented  **$('#addCustomerHeaderModal').modal('hide')** and now the value received by controller is no more NULL with IE. Don't know why modal-hide event behave like this with IE9.

Thanks for all the efforts in solving my problem guys :-)

Answer (score 2):

Based off the bit that you've shown, this is a simplified variation that may work more consistently, using `jQuery.post()` (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/):

```
var data = {
    CustName: $("#CustName").val(),
    CustLocalName: $("#CustLocalName").val(),
    CustNumber: $("#CustNumber").val(),
    CountryID: $("#SelectCountry").val(),
    City: $("#City").val()
};

$.post({
    '@Url.Action("CreateCustomerHeader", "CustomerHeader")',                  
    data,
    function(response, status, jqxhr){
        // do something with the response data
}).success(function () {
    $("#message").html("Success");
}).error(function () {
    $("#message").html("Save failed");
});
```

`$.post()` uses `$.ajax` as it's base, but abstracts some of the details away. For instance, `$.post` calls are not cached, so you don't need to set the `cache` state (and setting it is ignored if you do). Using a simple JavaScript object lets jQuery decide how to serialize the POST variables; when using this format, I rarely have issues with the model binder not being able to properly bind to my .NET classes.

`response` is whatever you send back from the controller; in your case, a JSON object. `status` is a simple text value like `success` or `error`, and `jqxhr` is a jQuery `XMLHttpRequest` object, which you *could* use to get some more information about the request, but I rarely find a need for it.

Comment: I have trying to use $.post as per ur suggestion (please refer to EDITED part of my question). Somehow it is still the same, working fine in Firefox but accepting NULL with IE9..

Comment: @anevil If these fields you're reading values from are inside of a form, you may want to try using `var data = $('#id-of-your-form').serialize()` rather than manually building the data object. It does seem strange, though.

Comment: the data is actually retrieve from modal, and i have try it by var formData = $('#addCustomerHeaderModal').serialize();.but it doesn't work :-(